# Permission denied after start container jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

When creating a jenkins container, the following errors appear. What could be the problem?

```
jenkins_1  | touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
jenkins_1  | Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
```

It is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    ports:
      - 7080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /tmp/jenkins-test:/var/jenkins_home
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [issue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/177).

`sudo chown 1000 /tmp/jenkins-test`

If the directory already contains files:

```
sudo chown -R 1000 volume_dir
```

> This will store the jenkins data in /your/home on the host. Ensure
>   that /your/home is accessible by the jenkins user in container
>   (jenkins user - uid 1000) or use -u some_other_user parameter with
>   docker run.
>
> You must set the correct permissions in the host before you mount
>   volumes `sudo chown 1000 volume_dir`

or you can try

Resolved albeit with torture involved.

Create a `jenkins` user on the host, note it's `uid`

```
docker run -u <jenkins-uid> ...
```

> Do NOT `docker run -u 'jenkins' -` This causes the container's own
>   jenkins user to continue to be used. Either choose a different name on
>   the host and pass this through or pass through the resultant uid.

A bash script that can you try to run

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $PWD/jenkins

sudo chown -R 1000:1000 $PWD/jenkins

docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins jenkins
```

Comment: how can i do this with docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Hi @АлексейЗемцов you can add this to the Dockerfile
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787360/error-with-jenkins-ecs-and-efs

Answer (score 0):

if after doing all the permission and all things still if its not working then just change the volumes mapping like this..

```
./your_folder:/var/jenkins_home
```

it will work fine..some time pwd is not works that will the create issue.